# jquery - Select the first <tr> that has <td> in <table>

Tags: html, jquery

As you know, some `<table>` start with `<tr><th>` excepts `<tr><td>`.
So how can we always select the first `<tr>` that has `<td>` in a table?

I tried but was unsuccessful.

```
$("tr:has(> td):first-child")
```

Comment: why not put your `th` in a `thead` and your `td` in `tbody`, then you can just use `tbody tr:first-child`

Comment: `$("td").first().closest("tr")`

Comment: You could try something like this `"tr:has(> td) td:first-of-type"`

Comment: You could use `:first` but that's deprecated, so `$("tr:has(>td)").first()` would work.  Note that `:first-child` may return multiple rows if you have multiple `<tbody>` elements (assuming it worked in the first place...)

Comment: There's an SO question about why `:first-child` not working - essentially `:first-child` will **always be the first-row** - but if you filter it out with `:has(>td)` (eg to get 2nd,3rd etc rows) then `:first-child` is none of those so the 1st row will not match.   ie it's always the first-row (row with index == 0), not the first-of-the-filtered results.  Use :first or .first() to get the 1st from the filtered results.

Comment: `$('tr:has(td)').first()`

Comment: @Pete: Your opinion is right. But this is a specific case for eg: when you have to process DOM by jquery and that DOM you received is not standard one. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is very close indeed. To select the first `tr` that has `td` use:

```
$("tr:has(td):first")
//OR
$("tr:has(td)").first()
//OR
$("tr:not(:has(th))").first()
```